# php application file storage structure

Tags: php, file-upload

i'm working on a web project what for each product i create several size for images and store them with prefix name like TH for thumbnail or LG for large in one directory that named storage and my question is that is it optimize method ? my friend suggest me store them to several directory like :
/storage/thumbnail/
/storage/large/
and i'm confused about it.

Answer (score 0):

Separating images as per their type in respected folder is good. It will help you in future to get information quickly without writing some lines of code to get the same.

for e.g: If you want to know, What is the total size of thumbnails you have?

Also, It will give a neat and clean file structure which will avoid confusions or mess.